# jacoco with both outputs: file and tcpserver

Tags: java, eclipse, jacoco

I am using eclipse 2019-12 in a JDK8 project and I want to check the coverage as I am using a web application through web Browser.
For this I have configured Tomcat Server 8 in eclipse and launched with two options (both OK):

- `-javaagent:"/tools/eclipse/dropins/jacoco-0.8.7/lib/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=127.0.0.1,port=8011,includes=com.mypckg.*"`
- `-javaagent:"C:\finconsum\tools\eclipse\dropins\jacoco-0.8.7\lib\jacocoagent.jar=output=file,destfile=/tmp/jacoco.exec,append=true,includes=com.mypckg.*"`

As I need to check what I am coveraging during the execution AND store the results for future reviews, is there any option to combine both outputs for the same execution?

Comment: In the _Coverage_ view, in the right-click menu there is _Export Session..._ and _Import Session..._. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any option to combine both outputs for the same execution?

according to https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html
valid values for `output` option are

> - file
> - tcpserver
> - tcpclient
> - none

so there is no "combined", however in case of execution

> `-javaagent:"/tools/eclipse/dropins/jacoco-0.8.7/lib/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=127.0.0.1,port=8011,includes=com.mypckg.*"`

after connection to server your client can retrieve data and store it also in file.